# How to run mindee doctr on specific area of image?

Tags: python, machine-learning, ocr

I am using below code to extract text from image with mindee/doctr package.

```py
from doctr.models import  ocr_predictor
from doctr.io import DocumentFile

import json
model = ocr_predictor( reco_arch='crnn_vgg16_bn', pretrained=True,export_as_straight_boxes=True)
image = DocumentFile.from_images("docs/temp.jpg")
result = model(image)
result_json = result.export()
json_object =  json.dumps(result_json, indent=4)

with open("temp.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)
result.show(image)
```

By using the mindee/doctr I got whole text form image in temp.json file.

Output after OCR:

[image]

I want to get text of specific area from the image.
What would be a good approach to achieve that?

Comment: Why don't you crop the image first?

Comment: I want specific fields so I can't crop image each time and every time

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches are possible:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(image_file).convert("RGB")

# if you know the area in which the info is located, you crop before OCR:
image = image.crop([x0, y0, x1, y1])
img_arr = np.asarray(image) 
ocr_result = model([img_arr])

# if you don't, you filter OCR results after:
ocr_output = ocr_result.export()
for block in ocr_output["pages"][0]["blocks"]:
    for line in block["lines"]:
        for word in line["words"]:
            xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = word["geometry"]
            if word["value"] == "i want that value":  # add your filtering condition on "value", "geometry", whatever
                word["filtered"] = 0  # here I add a field, but you can also delete the word or do whatever you want
```